# Run .vbs script through a task scheduler on android phone

Tags: android, excel, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, vba

I have an Excel sheet with VBA code and a .vbs script to automatically run the VBA code in Windows Task Scheduler.

When the VBA code is run it sends an email through Outlook. My laptop has to be switched on to perform this.

My new requirement is to perform this same system, on my Android phone, since it is always switched on unlike my laptop.

**If I copy the Excel file and .vbs script to my phone:**

1. **How do I run the .vbs script on my Android phone?**

   **Is there any application similar to wscript or cscript for Android phones?**
2. **Are there applications similar to Windows Task Scheduler for Android phones (to schedule the running of the vbscript)?**

Comment: Seems like there is no solution to this problem at the moment

Comment: You might want to check out any of the 'wake-on lan' apps in the play store and then have your vb script run when laptop starts.

Comment: @mrbungle Cant i copy the excel sheet and the vbscript to the phone and run the vbscript on the phone?

Comment: Two different OS. "VBScript is a Microsoft language designed to run on Microsoft operating systems with Windows Scripting Host installed"

Answer (score 0):

The Android OS is based on the linux kernel and cannot run windows visual basic.  You would need to rewrite this solution to something Android understands.  You have a few options available on the Android platform.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_Layer_for_Android

- Python using CPython
- Perl
- Ruby using JRuby
- Lua
- BeanShell
- JavaScript using Rhino
- Tcl
- Rexx using BRexx

Comment: Thank you very much
Are there applications similar to Windows Task Scheduler for Android phones ?

Comment: Android is based on the Linux kernel which typically uses cron to schedule tasks.  Having said that the android store has a bunch of task scheduler apps available for download, like TaskBomb.

Comment: Oh ok then my second issue of a task scheduler should not be a problem

Comment: Hopping into this party nice and late... But! You can now do these kinds and of things with ms power automate.